# How can I draw this effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, gradient, illustrator-effects, pixel-grid

Does anybody know how to draw this in illustrator?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hello Raimir and welcome to GDSE! Can you tell us more about what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: Hi. To be honest, I think it would be easier to make something like this in a raster image editor.  Have a look at [the mosaic filter in Photsohop](https://imgur.com/wHs8Hg8) as a starting point.

Comment: What have you tied? Where it that failing?

Comment: I tried with mosaic filter in photoshop. That's all.. in answer below, i understood what i was miss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Illustrator is the best tool for this, so I'll show a solution for Photoshop. Don't know if you're interested in that.

Let's start with some slightly blurred image.

[image]

First use *Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic* to pixelate the image.

Here I used these settings:

[image]

[image]

Then use *Filter > Sharpen > Unsharp Mask* to apply those shadows to the pixels.

Here I used these settings:

[image]

[image]

Finally you could apply some *Filter > Blur > Blur* to soften the image a little:

[image]

Comment: Oh Man!!! Thanks a lot! This is it! I passed through same path, but i didnt guess about sharpen!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a long rectangle shape and fill monochrome gradient. Preferably (say 70%) transparent.

[image]

2. Duplicate it several times to create a set. Group all and again copy and paste same and reverse the gradient direction (or horizontally flip the group).

[image]

3. Combine both groups. Group them again and make a copy and rotate it 90 degress and place over it. Now group everything. Let's call it **GRID**.

[image]

4. Draw some random shapes with different colors and group them and apply *Effect > Blur > Guassian Blur*. Let's call it COLORS and *place* it behind the GRID. Change blend mode of GRID to *Multiply*. You may want to decrease the overall opacity of GRID if you need. I've set it to 83% (random). You should get this:

[image]

5. Now create a large black rectangle and subtract a random shape from it, according to your requirement.

[image]

6. Apply *Blur* to it. Set blend mode to Multiply. Group everything and clip mask the area you need:

[image]

[image]

---

I don't know if Illustrator has something inbuilt for things like. I know basics. But this is just a method from scratch to try and get similar effect. There are many things in this, that can be done better or needs fix, especially the dark unwanted vertical/horizontal line right in the middle. There are many things to explore.

You can try different opacities, different gradient colors in the rectangles of GRID, blend modes etc. Whatever works best. I have given the idea how one can approach things like this.